# Ruby 1.9.3 installed, but still says I'm running Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: rvm

I just used RVM to update my Ruby version to 1.9.3 from 1.8.7. Everything compiled and worked perfectly (as far as I can tell, no errors from RVM or anything), but when I type `ruby -v`, my machine tells me I'm still running 1.8.7. Did I miss a step in my installation? I'm running OSX Lion.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`? How about `rvm current`?

Comment: I also had a similar obstacle, once I restarted terminal session the Ruby -v updated to 1.9.3 from 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
rvm use 1.9.3
ruby -v
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Guess I missed that step. Will accept the answer when SO will let me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I install ruby 1.9.3 and make sure it persists across shells:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash # install rvm
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448 --install  # install ruby 1.9.3
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3-p448  # set ruby 1.9.3 as the default version
```